# Vertically flip text

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using [Fontstash](https://github.com/akrinke/Font-Stash) to load and render my text. However when I draw, the text is vertically flipped:
[flipped text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFjM.png)

I cannot change the origin so I think I have to rotate the texture [here](https://github.com/akrinke/Font-Stash/blob/master/fontstash.c#L600), however I'm not sure how to do it or if it's the proper way.

I set the matrices like this:

```
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glViewport(0, 0, viewport[2], viewport[3]);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0, viewport[2], viewport[3], 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: That rendering code doesn't set much in the way of state and it uses older (not modern) OpenGL.  So you'll want to make sure your viewport and model-view-projection matrices are correctly in *your* render loop (which maybe you should show code for in your question).  Look for (glViewport, glMatrixMode, and whatever matrix functions you use to establish your camera)

Comment: Alright, I have edited my post

Comment: So are ALL the coordinates flipped or just the text?  You could flip your ortho matrix `glOrtho(0, viewport[2], 0, viewport[3], -1, 1);`  I'm also still trying to understand your "I cannot change the origin" constraint.  Why not?

Comment: Only the text is flipped, I tried flipping the ortho matrix but the text is just not displaying or maybe out of bounds. Concerning the constraint, I'm not sure fontstash support that (I'm working with legacy code) hence I have thought about rotating the texture.

Comment: If you flipped the viewport and nothing showed up, it could be because you have face culling enabled (`glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`) which defaults to culling the back face according to the _winding order_, which is default to `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)`, and you'd have to change this to `GL_CW` if you flip things in Y but not X.  (If it's being used at all).

Comment: It works! I will post this as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wyck pointed out that I had face culling enabled, disabling it resolved the issue just fine when flipping the orthographic matrix.